# sql doesnt 'execute' INSERT INTO statement..but the code weirdly works

Tags: php

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
include 'db.php';
$title=$_POST['title'];
$desc=$_POST['desc'];

try{
$sql=" INSERT INTO posttbl (title,desc)
VALUES ('$title','$desc')" ;
$e=$pdo->exec($sql);
}catch (PDOexception $e){
$error="error inserting";
include 'error.php';
exit();
}
header('Location:/test/');




}
?>

*/////////FORM

<html>
<body>

<h3>Add item</h3>
<form action="" method="POST">
Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br />
Item Description: <textarea name="desc" id="comment" type="text"></textarea><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />  

</form>
```

the code is working but its not inserting anything into my database..am i missing something? or doing something isnt right? my database consist of 3 columns..postid,title and desc...so whats wrong? is it the if isset($_POST["submit"])){???or something else?

Comment: What value is standing in $e?

Comment: And I guess $pdo is really a PDO-Object ;)

Comment: Once check the DB connections in your db.php... I doubt there may be an error in DB connection..

Comment: share your db.php file

Answer (score 0):

this the right syntaxe of insert row into PDO

```
try {
$var = array(
  'title' => $title,
  'desc' => $desc
);
$req = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO posttbl (title,desc) VALUE (:title,:desc)");
$req->execute($var);} catch (Exception $e) {    
echo $e->getMessage();}
```